# Mail not send on Forget Password in HumHub

Tags: php, email, yii

I'm! creating my own social networking portal Using "HUMHUB" with YII framework most of the things works fine. I set up mail setting to "php sendmail" for sending mail on forget password. It redirects to success page but no mail received by users.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Sendmail or alternative SMTP server is configured in the server?

Comment: Yes SMTP Configuration also there and I disabled it by choosing PHP sendmail, but why this not working.